# Haskell does not garbage collect the head of a list?

Tags: performance, haskell, garbage-collection

Consider the following program:

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad.List

main = runListT $ do
  x <- ListT $ return $ [0..1000000000]
  lift $ print x
```

Ideally, we would want the list to be garbage collected as we consume it, so that this program only uses constant memory. But when I compile and run it with

`ghc Main.hs -O2 -o Main`

I see that it keep using more and more memory. How do I convince Haskell to GC the consumed elements of the list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `ListT` in `transformers` doesn't stream or run in constant space.  The `ListT` in `pipes` does!

```
import Control.Monad (mzero)
import Pipes

main = runListT (do
    x <- Select (each [0..1000000000])
    lift (print x)
    mzero )
```

I also just uploaded `pipes-4.1.4` today, which relaxes `runListT` to not require the `mzero` at the end, so then it would just be:

```
-- Requires `pipes-4.1.4`
import Pipes

main = runListT (do
    x <- Select (each [0..1000000000])
    lift (print x) )
```